# Construct a query using glue but make it not a string

Tags: r, aws-glue

I am working in rstudio with a r script that reads a sql script using glue. My r script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
library(glue)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "Athena") 

day_from <- 7
day_to <- 30
game_name <- 'fungame'
query <- read_lines("example.sql") %>% glue_collapse(sep = "\n") %>% glue_sql(.con = con)
setosa <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
setosa %>% glimpse()
```

My sql script query.sql:

```
/*a comment describing the query*/
with


/*
Athena installs data. After deducting the training period, get the preceding 90 days of installs for training.
*/
installs as (
select s, 
       install_dt, 
       split(game_name, '_')[2] as platform,
       case when country = 'United States' then 1 else 0 end as usa
from device_metrics.game_install
where year || '-' || month || '-' || day >= date_format(date_add('day', -({day_to} + 91), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
and year || '-' || month || '-' || day <= date_format(date_add('day', -({day_to} + 1), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
and regexp_like(lower(game_name), ('^(?!.*QA).*' || {game_name} || '.*')) -- excludes 'QA' devices
),


/* 
Get marketing data from adx.
Full quarter of training data with at least one full day_m day cycle i.e. last full quarter + day_m days 
*/
adx_min as (
select 
  adx_id,
  publisher_name,
  row_number() over(partition by adx_id order by time_stamp asc) rn -- some dups, get first instance of an install
from blah_ui_dev.adxdata_match_v2
where lower(game_name) = {game_name}
and concat(yy,'-',mm,'-',dd) >= date_format(date_add('day', -({day_to} + 91), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
and concat(yy,'-',mm,'-',dd) <= date_format(date_add('day', -({day_to} + 1), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
),


/*
Dedupped installs based on earliest timestamp
*/
adx as (
select 
  adx_id,
  publisher_name
from adx_min
where rn = 1
),


/*
installs and marketing dta where exists
use min/max to dedup, some cases with a single s assoociated with multiple platforms
*/
installs_base as (
select 
  i.s,
  i.usa,
  min(i.install_dt) as install_dt,
  min(i.platform) as platform,
  min(a.publisher_name) as publisher_name
from installs i 
left join adx a on upper(if(i.s like 'IDFV%', substr(i.s,6), i.s)) = a.adx_id 
group by i.s, i.usa
),


/*
day n sessions count
*/
sessions_day_from as (
select i.s,
       count(1) as sessions_day_from,
       sum(session_length) / 1000 as sum_session_time_day_from
from installs_base i        
join device_metrics.user_game_session sess on sess.s = i.s
where regexp_like(lower(sess.game_name), '^(?!.*QA).*' || {game_name} || '.*')
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), date_parse(sess.activity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= {day_from}
group by i.s
),


/*
day n utility
*/
utility_day_from as (
select 
  u.s,
  sum(u.utility) as utility_day_from
from installs_base i
join adhoc.device_sessions_daily u on u.s = i.s
where lower(u.game_base) = {game_name}
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), u.activity_date) <= {day_from}
group by u.s
),


/*
recent utility. Are users continuing to play the game more recently or did they drop off.
*/
utility_recent as (
select 
  u.s,
  sum(u.utility) as recent_utility_sum
from installs_base i
join adhoc.device_sessions_daily u on u.s = i.s
where lower(u.game_base) = {game_name}
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), u.activity_date) <= floor({day_from} / 2)
group by u.s
),


/*
day n spend
*/
spend_day_from as (
select 
  i.s, 
  sum(dr.amt) as spend_day_from
from device_metrics.daily_revenue dr
join installs_base i on i.s = dr.s
where coalesce(channel,'IAP') = 'IAP'
and regexp_like(lower(game_name), ('^(?!.*QA).*' || {game_name} || '.*')) -- excludes 'QA' devices
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), date_parse(dr.activity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= {day_from}
group by 1
),


/*
day m target spend (target)
*/
spend_day_to as (
select 
  i.s, 
  sum(dr.amt) as spend_day_to
from device_metrics.daily_revenue dr
join installs_base i on i.s = dr.s
where coalesce(channel,'IAP') = 'IAP'
and regexp_like(lower(game_name), ('^(?!.*QA).*' || {game_name} || '.*')) -- excludes 'QA' devices
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), date_parse(dr.activity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= {day_to}
group by 1
)


select 
  i.s,
  i.install_dt,
  i.platform,
  i.usa,
  i.publisher_name,
  coalesce(sn.sessions_day_from, 0) as {glue('sessions_day_{day_from}')},
  coalesce(sn.sum_session_time_day_from, 0) as {glue('sum_session_time_day_{day_from}')},
  coalesce(un.utility_day_from, 0) as {glue('utility_day_{day_from}')},
  coalesce(spn.spend_day_from, 0) as {glue('spend_day_{day_from}')},
  round(coalesce(ru.recent_utility_sum / un.utility_day_from, 0), 2) as recent_utility_ratio,
  coalesce(spm.spend_day_to, 0) as {glue('spend_day_{day_to}')} 
from installs_base i 
left join sessions_day_from sn on sn.s = i.s 
left join utility_day_from un on un.s = i.s 
left join spend_day_from spn on spn.s = i.s
left join utility_recent ru on ru.s = i.s
left join spend_day_to spm on spm.s = i.s
```

I can see what the sql looks like in the console by typing the variable name query:

```
query
<SQL> -- !preview conn=con

/*DDA day day_from to day day_to training data query*/
with


/*
Athena installs data. After deducting the training period, get the preceeding 90 days of installs for training.
*/
installs as (
select s, 
       install_dt, 
       split(game_name, '_')[2] as platform,
       case when country = 'United States' then 1 else 0 end as usa
from device_metrics.game_install
where year || '-' || month || '-' || day >= date_format(date_add('day', -(30 + 91), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
and year || '-' || month || '-' || day <= date_format(date_add('day', -(30 + 1), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
and regexp_like(lower(game_name), ('^(?!.*QA).*' || 'fungame' || '.*')) -- excludes 'QA' devices
),


/* 
Get marketing data from adx.
Full quarter of training data with at least one full day_m day cycle i.e. last full quarter + day_m days 
*/
adx_min as (
select 
  adx_id,
  publisher_name,
  row_number() over(partition by adx_id order by time_stamp asc) rn -- some dups, get first instance of an install
from glu_ui_dev.adxdata_match_v2
where lower(game_name) = 'fungame'
and concat(yy,'-',mm,'-',dd) >= date_format(date_add('day', -(30 + 91), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
and concat(yy,'-',mm,'-',dd) <= date_format(date_add('day', -(30 + 1), current_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
),


/*
Dedupped installs based on earliest timestamp
*/
adx as (
select 
  adx_id,
  publisher_name
from adx_min
where rn = 1
),


/*
installs and marketing dta where exists
use min/max to dedup, some cases with a single s assoociated with multiple platforms
*/
installs_base as (
select 
  i.s,
  i.usa,
  min(i.install_dt) as install_dt,
  min(i.platform) as platform,
  min(a.publisher_name) as publisher_name
from installs i 
left join adx a on upper(if(i.s like 'IDFV%', substr(i.s,6), i.s)) = a.adx_id 
group by i.s, i.usa
),


/*
day n sessions count
*/
sessions_day_from as (
select i.s,
       count(1) as sessions_day_from,
       sum(session_length) / 1000 as sum_session_time_day_from
from installs_base i        
join device_metrics.user_game_session sess on sess.s = i.s
where regexp_like(lower(sess.game_name), '^(?!.*QA).*' || 'fungame' || '.*')
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), date_parse(sess.activity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= 7
group by i.s
),


/*
day n utility
*/
utility_day_from as (
select 
  u.s,
  sum(u.utility) as utility_day_from
from installs_base i
join adhoc.device_sessions_daily u on u.s = i.s
where lower(u.game_base) = 'fungame'
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), u.activity_date) <= 7
group by u.s
),


/*
recent utility. Are users continuing to play the game more recently or did they drop off.
*/
utility_recent as (
select 
  u.s,
  sum(u.utility) as recent_utility_sum
from installs_base i
join adhoc.device_sessions_daily u on u.s = i.s
where lower(u.game_base) = 'fungame'
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), u.activity_date) <= floor(7 / 2)
group by u.s
),


/*
day n spend
*/
spend_day_from as (
select 
  i.s, 
  sum(dr.amt) as spend_day_from
from device_metrics.daily_revenue dr
join installs_base i on i.s = dr.s
where coalesce(channel,'IAP') = 'IAP'
and regexp_like(lower(game_name), ('^(?!.*QA).*' || 'fungame' || '.*')) -- excludes 'QA' devices
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), date_parse(dr.activity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= 7
group by 1
),


/*
day m target spend (target)
*/
spend_day_to as (
select 
  i.s, 
  sum(dr.amt) as spend_day_to
from device_metrics.daily_revenue dr
join installs_base i on i.s = dr.s
where coalesce(channel,'IAP') = 'IAP'
and regexp_like(lower(game_name), ('^(?!.*QA).*' || 'fungame' || '.*')) -- excludes 'QA' devices
and date_diff('day', date_parse(i.install_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), date_parse(dr.activity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) <= 30
group by 1
)


select 
  i.s,
  i.install_dt,
  i.platform,
  i.usa,
  i.publisher_name,
  coalesce(sn.sessions_day_from, 0) as 'sessions_day_7',
  coalesce(sn.sum_session_time_day_from, 0) as 'sum_session_time_day_7',
  coalesce(un.utility_day_from, 0) as 'utility_day_7',
  coalesce(spn.spend_day_from, 0) as 'spend_day_7',
  round(coalesce(ru.recent_utility_sum / un.utility_day_from, 0), 2) as recent_utility_ratio,
  coalesce(spm.spend_day_to, 0) as 'spend_day_30' 
from installs_base i 
left join sessions_day_from sn on sn.s = i.s 
left join utility_day_from un on un.s = i.s 
left join spend_day_from spn on spn.s = i.s
left join utility_recent ru on ru.s = i.s
left join spend_day_to spm on spm.s = i.s
```

The issue I'm posting about is specifically in the very bottom select field name section. After the 'as', my field names are string quoted.

Glue returns the part after 'as' as a string. This does not seem to cause problems in this case, however, in my actual script I'm using odbc with Athena, and it doesn't like the fact that the query is of the form `select field_name as 'string'` as opposed to the regular `select field_name as string` // string is not quoted as a string

Is there a way to have glue compose this part after 'as' outwith string quotes? Desired query:

```
<SQL> 
    select
      Species as Species-setosa
    from iris
    where species = 'setosa'
```

Comment: Can you try by adding this to the end `%>%%>% str_replace_all("(?<=as )'|'(?=\nfrom)", "") %>% glue_sql(.con = con)`

Comment: Hi @akrun where exactly? Within the sql script in here `Species as {glue('Species-{var1}')}`?

Comment: I meant after you got the `query` i.e. `query %>% str_replace_all("(?<=as )'|'(?=\nfrom)", "") %>% glue_sql(.con = con)`

Comment: For me, it is giving the unquoted version

Comment: Yes! Except if I have more than one field to select it doesn't quote work e.g. `select
  Species as {glue('Species-{var1}')},
  Species as {glue('OtherSpecies-{var1}')}
from iris
where species = {var1}`

Comment: It would replace the quotes whenever there is `as `

Comment: With more than one field, after passing query through your snippet, I get: `<SQL> select
  Species as Species-setosa',
  Species as OtherSpecies-setosa
from iris
where species = 'setosa'`. There's a quote after 'Species-setosa'

Comment: ok, got it, you can change the pattern to `query %>% str_replace_all("(?<=as )'|'(?=(\nfrom|,))", "") %>% glue_sql(.con = con)`

Comment: Can you check if it removed the quotes.  But, I have a doubt.  If your value have some spaces, then do you use backquotes?

Comment: This is great! Thank you again for helping. Would be interested to udnerstand those `regex in str_replace_all()`?

Comment: Is it the full query in the example.sql

Comment: I get some errors `Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'day_to' not found`

Comment: maybe you can `dput` the query

Comment: Updated now, I realize it's a lot longer than my original post, I was trying to be minimal

Comment: It is a bit long :-) where all you need to change the quotes.  If you do `dput(query)` it may. give the correct structure

Comment: Yeah, but I think the problem areas are still small. It's the original problem basically but without harming this line further up: `left join adx a on upper(if(i.s like 'IDFV%', substr(i.s,6), i.s)) = a.adx_id `

If we could remove the quoptes around the select field alias' at the bottom while not removing the single quote `'` around `'IDFV%'` that would be it. You're original solution solves the problem with e.g. coalesce(sn.sessions_day_from, 0) as 'sessions_day_7' by removing the quotes around sessions_day_7, but in doing so removes the closing quote around `'IDFV%'`

Comment: Can you try `query %>%
     str_replace_all("(?<=as )'|(?<![%])'(?=(\nfrom|,))", "") %>%
     glue_sql(.con = con)`

Comment: That solves it yes! Thanks a lot Akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to replace the `'` by matching the quote on a specific location with regex lookaround.  Here, we can use `str_replace_all`

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
query %>%
     str_replace_all("(?<=as )'|(?<![%])'(?=(\nfrom|,))", "") %>%
     glue_sql(.con = con)
#<SQL> select
#  Species as Species-setosa
#from iris
#where species = 'setosa'
```

We match the `'` that follows the word `as` and a space or (`|`) the `'` the precedes either a comma (`,`) or nextline and from (`\nfrom`)

Comment: If I may with a follow up... my actual SQL script has a lot more sql and the regex is interfering further up. This line: `left join adx a on upper(if(i.s like 'IDFV%', substr(i.s,6), i.s)) = a.adx_id ` is having the quote removed after the % sign so it reads like this: `left join adx a on upper(if(i.s like 'IDFV%, substr(i.s,6), i.s)) = a.adx_id `. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I'm still absorbing what the regex is doing

Comment: @DougFir that is basically because of the matching with the comma.  That is an issue with regex if we. ddon't know what alll patterns you. have in the file.  I see that `,` followed by substr while in the previous case it is `, Species`, so you may need `str_replace_all("(?<=as )'|'(?=(\nfrom|, Species))", "")`

Comment: Thanks again here. This solves the issue of removing the quote after the % but then reintroduces a single quote at the end of select: `select something as blah'` line

Comment: @DougFir Can you update with the full query as the regex I considered was based on the query you showed

Comment: You can just update with `My sql script query.sql:`

Comment: Added that now to my post. I don't understand your last comment? A sincere thanks again for helping out here

Comment: I meant to. update the script query.sql part. thanks